# C++ Mac OS infinite loop in regex_replace if given blank regex expression

Tags: c++, regex, macos

Upon executing...

```
std::regex_replace("the string", std::regex(""), "doesn't matter");
```

...my Mac will hang indefinitely. I'm new to xcode, but I think I am using it correctly. I hit "pause" while debugging the program and found the last executed code is deep within the regex library. I need blank regex to work because the user may input blank.

This does not occur on Windows (I'm developing cross-platform).

This does not occur with `std::regex_match()`.

Comment: If you want to check for an empty string, then check for an empty string, don't use a regular expression for something that simple.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but it will result in more lines of code that I'd like (I need to check this many times over). The solution I would have liked would be something like `if (regex("").size())  regex_replace(etc...)` but the regex docs don't have any information on getting regex attributes.

Comment: Lines of code is a bad metric. And using regular expression will be way more costly than a simple `the_string.empty()` check.

Comment: alright, best solution (for my situation): for every regex variable, make another with _s at the end to hold the original regex... also, I should find a better regex library when I get the time.

Comment: I don't mean you should check any `regex` object attribute, but that the *input string* from the user is empty or not before you call `regex_replace`.

Comment: I know Joachim, thanks! It's just that I setup my user inputs code, so essentially I can only get the user input once, and checking it would use up "the one time" aspect of it. So I need to save it in a variable and then checl... anyway my user input code is based on a limitation of the software that I hope to soon bypass with a better UI system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the root cause, see the [*regex.cpp* source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libcpp/libcpp-31/src/regex.cpp) at [Apple Open Source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/):

```
case regex_constants::__re_err_empty:
    return "An empty regex is not allowed in the POSIX grammar.";
```

So, you have to check the user input and disallow passing an empty string to create a regex object.

Comment: just looked and windows regex source code there is a public _Empty() as in usage example: `expr._Empty()` returns a bool. If you look for that in source code you'll find "match returns false if empty" code. There's gotta be something with mac regex that holds the size or the original string. But whatever, the fact that the regex implementation is different on mac a win... really annoying. I want to get familiar with boost at some point.

Comment: I'm not sure about Mac, but shouldn't exception causes the program to crash instead of hanging?