# c++ mac os x regex(".*") causes infinite loop with regex_replace()

Tags: c++, regex, macos, infinite-loop

This causes infinite loop:

```
std::regex_replace("the string", std::regex(".*"), "whatevs");
```

This DOES NOT cause infinite loop:

```
std::regex_replace("the string", std::regex("^.*$"), "whatevs");
```

What is wrong with Mac regex implementation? using Mac OS X El Capitan Xcode 7.1

this question is related to: [C++ Mac OS infinite loop in regex_replace if given blank regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574723/c-mac-os-infinite-loop-in-regex-replace-if-given-blank-regex-expression)

Comment: Obviously, it has something to do with only accepting matches from the start of the string vs accepting matches anywhere in the string. And the string is constantly growing.

Comment: `.*` matches the empty string after the entire input string has been processed. If you change the regex to no longer match the empty processed string (`^.*`, `..*`, `.+`, etc.), then it does not loop indefinitely. I'm not sure if the standard says what should happen when the regex will match the empty string.

Comment: [Note that libstdc++ results in two copies of the output: `whatevswhatevs`](http://ideone.com/e0Vb5Z) (I believe it to be because the regex matches `the string`, which is replaced with `whatevs`, and then the regex matches the remaining input (the empty string) and so gets another `whatevs` appended to it).

Comment: It is a bug in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

The `.*` matches the whole string first, and then the empty string at the end because `*` means "*match 0 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern*". The empty string match is probably the cause of the infinite loop, but I'm not sure whether it's a bug or by-design.

You can override the behavior using `std::regex_constants::match_not_null` (see [`regex_replace` c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/)):

> **`match_not_null`**  Not null  **Empty sequences do not match.**

[C++ code demo](http://ideone.com/CA7anV) returning `whatevs` only:

```
std::regex reg(".*");
std::string s = "the string";
std::cout << std::regex_replace(s, reg, "whatevs",    
         std::regex_constants::match_not_null) << std::endl;
```

Note that the "infinite loop" you observe is most likely a bug since the source code hints that an exception should be thrown once an empty string is passed to the regex engine. It is not yet logged anywhere. I think (not sure) the issue might be with how the string is handled by the `regex_replace` method when matches are collected for a replace operation.

Here is what happens: The `regex_replace` calls

```
basic_string<_Elem, _Traits1, _Alloc1> regex_replace(const basic_string<_Elem, _Traits1, _Alloc1>& _Str, const basic_regex<_Elem, _RxTraits>& _Re, const _Elem *_Ptr, regex_constants::match_flag_type _Flgs = regex_constants::match_default)
{   // search and replace, string result, string target, NTBS format
    basic_string<_Elem, _Traits1, _Alloc1> _Res;
    const basic_string<_Elem> _Fmt(_Ptr);
    regex_replace(_STD back_inserter(_Res), _Str.begin(), _Str.end(),
        _Re, _Fmt, _Flgs);
    return (_Res);
}
```

`_Res` is an empty string, `_Fmt` is now *whatevs*. Then, the `regex_replace` is called. `_Str.end()` equals `10`, and a pointer is initialized.

`_First` equals *the string* and `_Last` equals an empty string.

[image]

It happens as a result of internal char buffer processing whose pointer actually contains an array of:

[image]

The `inline back_insert_iterator<_Container> back_inserter(_Container& _Cont)` method first creates a string out of the first 0 to 9 chars, and then from 10 to 15 array elements (the one starting with the null terminator).

Comment: I think it's more of a bug here rather than something that can be explained by regex syntax. See Cornstalks's comment.

Comment: @nhahtdh: It is possible that it is a bug, but there is a way to work around it using the flag I mention.

Comment: Please make it clear that it's a workaround for the bug, rather than attempting to explain this specific behavior in Mac.

Comment: @nhahtdh: First, this is not only Mac behavior. Second, why must it be a bug (maybe it is ByDesign?). Third, I do not explain, I state that the engine matches a null string as the second match value - no idea why it acts like this. Fourth, I have posted a valid way to obtain expected results. If you have another idea, please post your own answer.

Comment: `First, this is not only Mac behavior.` The infinite loop is Mac only behaviour, as far as I can see. `Second, why must it be a bug (maybe it is ByDesign?).` Infinite loop for regex replacement is more likely to be a bug, rather than something allowed by the standard. And the previous question also involves zero-length match, which is likely the source of the bug. Another thing, "null string" doesn't make sense - it can match an empty string at the end, though. I can't really post an answer yet, since I haven't pinpointed the root cause of the bug.

Comment: It is a bug. It may or may not be a Mac-only bug, but it is a bug. If this is By Design, then this is a bug in The Design (but I don't believe that, as the design is not original and well-tested).

Comment: @n.m.: I agree the array I have just debugged into is not expected, and what is not expected is a bug to me.

Comment: This answer did not solve my problem... I am not 100% certain that my code is correct, but I really think the right answer is "std regex on mac is buggy, avoid usage." `.*` should work, otherwise the regex engine is useless for my project.

Comment: @ElanHickler: Let's say `.*` is a useless pattern. What do you need to match?

Comment: keep in mind `anything goes here.*` has the same problem of `.*`

Comment: also keep in mind if I wanted to avoid infinite loop bug, I'd have to write a regex pre-parser to ensure the regex is "correct" before going to regex(). this is ludicrous.

Comment: Why not adding `$` after final `.*` in the pattern? It should fix the issue. BTW, do you mean to say the `match_not_null` does not work?

Comment: The input to the regex is from the end user. I've been using `.*` for years. https://regex101.com/r/uX2eM3/1 see as how `.*` matches only once. This is how regex is supposed to work. `.*$` is verbose and will be annoying to the end user. Ok... I'm starting to figure out the very specific caveats. What I could do is `if string is not empty, use match_not_null flag`. That works. Sorry, I had my code wrong so I didn't test match_not_null at first; now I'm using boost_regex, which actually needs match_not_null in this case.

Comment: @stribizhev is there any trick to that I can use to format the input string so that `.*` matches `""` as well as `"something"` (matches once)? My own answer addresses this problem with flags, but maybe pre-formatting the input is better.

Comment: I don't have the environment, so I'll share my findings with you. Source code of regex: https://opensource.apple.com/source/libcpp/libcpp-31/include/regex (the one linked in your other answer is only a small part). Bug report: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21751 (this is about regex_iterator, but regex_replace is implemented with regex_iterator, and the code also involves empty string match)

Answer (score 0):

**stribizhev's** answer inspired this one. Here are example results using various flags:

---

### GOOD

`boost::regex_replace(input, match, replace, input.empty() ? boost::regex_constants::match_default : boost::regex_constants::match_not_null);`

> results:
>
> ```
> input:   ""
> match:   ".*"
> replace: "a"
> output:  "a"
>
> input:   "something"
> match:   ".*"
> replace: "a"
> output:  "a"
> ```

---

### BAD

`boost::regex_replace(input, match, replace, boost::regex_constants::match_not_null);`

> results:
>
> ```
> input:   ""
> match:   ".*"
> replace: "a"
> output:  ""
>
> input:   "something"
> match:   ".*"
> replace: "a"
> output:  "a"
> ```

---

### BAD

`boost::regex_replace(input, match, replace);`

> results:
>
> ```
> input:   ""
> match:   ".*"
> replace: "a"
> output:  "a"
>
> input:   "something"
> match:   ".*"
> replace: "a"
> output:  "aa"
> ```