# Strange result in extracting regex

Tags: regex, r

I don't know why I'm receiving `""` sign while extracting `".*"` regex in `R`.
Here is the code and the result I receive.

```
library(stringr)
y <- enc2utf8("a ala asia kasia stasia karolina")
str_extract_all(y, regex(".*"))[[1]]
[1] "a ala asia kasia stasia karolina" ""
```

Is this normal or this may be the case of operating system settings?

This is my `Sys.getlocale`:

```
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250;LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250;
LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250"
```

Comment: I am interested if `perl(".*")` regex would also return the same result.

Comment: @stribizhev If you read the source code for `str_extract_all()` you will probably find this in the implementation.  I am just explaining the observations.

Comment: Does `^.*$` meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that R packages are running C code under the hood (and [*stringr* is not an exception](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html): *As of version 1.0, `stringr` is a thin wrapper around [`stringi`](https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/), which implements all the functions in `stringr` with efficient C code based on the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/)*.) and a similar ["bug" with `std::regex` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33799633/3832970) makes me believe it has to do with how the strings are split internally to return the matched subtexts.

The best practice is to ***never use an unachored regex that may match an empty string***. While in some languages the regex might work alright, in others it may cause serious issues (infinite loops, or duplicated replacements, etc.)

So, if you want to match any string that can be empty or not with `str_extract_all`, use anchors:

```
^.*$
```

Note that `gsub` does not have the bug, `gsub(".*", "new string", "old")` returns `new string`, it seems to be the problem with this package.