# Why there are two matches

Tags: regex

I think that there is a match,but there are two.That's strange.I want to know why

[image]

Comment: A known fact actually. What is the tool? What regex flavor does it work with? PCRE?

Comment: I hope [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795759/c-mac-os-x-regex-causes-infinite-loop-with-regex-replace/33799633#33799633) will provide a glimpse into what the problem may lie in. From what I know, this issue happens because of how the string is split internally by C++. That is why it is never a good idea to use patterns all subpatterns in which can match empty strings. Use `^.*$` to avoid any issue with `.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you surprised? `.*` matches any number of characters, including 0.

So you get one match that contains the entire line, and a second match that contains the empty string between the first match and the end of the string.

Regular expressions don't just deal with characters, but also with positions between characters (known as [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)). For example `^` matches the position *before* the first character, `$` matches the position *after* the last character in a string.

A regex engine "walks through" a string, starting from the position before the first character. It then steps forward one character at a time.

For example, when applying the regex `.*` to `"Hello"`, the regex engine starts before the `H`. It then matches `Hello` - after that `.*` can't match any more characters, so the regex engine returns `"Hello"` as the first match. The regex engine is now positioned after the `o`. If you call it again and ask it to match, it will succeed in returning a match because you're asking it to match any string, even an empty one, from the current position - and that's possible.

Why doesn't the regex engine return an infinite number of empty strings, then? It checks whether the last match was started from the end of the string, and if it was, no further matches will be attempted.

Some languages don't even try a regex match once from the final position in a string (Ruby seems to be one example), but I'd say it's more correct to return two matches.

Since it appears more clarification is necessary: The regex engine steps through the string along the positions visualized by `|`s below:

```
"|H|e|l|l|o|"
 ^ Position before the first character
           ^ Position after the last character
```

Comment: what's the meaning of the end of the string?I don't understand.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Python strings don't have null terminators, and `re.findall(".*", "foo")` still returns `["foo", ""]`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Ok, however, the two matches I observed come from the fact that the string was split during matching into the whole string of characters, and the end position. `.*` matches both. That is all I wanted to share.

Comment: why .*$ also return two matches.after adding '$',it should return one match. '^.*' return one match,that's why?

Comment: `.*$` matches the empty string after the last character in the string, so you get two matches. `^.*` has to match from the start of the string, so it can only return one match (after all, after it has found the first match, it's no longer at the start of the string).

Comment: can you tell me what's the last character.why the engine stop before the last character,i think the engine should include the last character,because the regex is greedy

Comment: It doesn't stop before the last character. It stops after the last character. And there are zero characters between that position and the end of the string, because these two positions are identical. But since your regex allows zero characters to be matched, the empty string can be matched at that position.