# Regex: unexpected double replacement

Tags: regex, scala

If I write this in Scala:

```
System.err println "Done".replaceAll(".*$", "$0xyz")
```

Then the output is unexpectedly not `Donexyz` but `Donexyzxyz`.

I have some idea of what's going on – `Done` is being turned into `Donexyz`, and then a second replacement is happening, matching against `Donexyz` and turning it into `Donexyzxyz`. (Using `replaceFirst` produces `Donexyz`, confirming this.) But that doesn't explain everything -- in particular I don't know why we don't get

```
Done -> Donexyz -> Donexyzxyz -> Donexyzxyzxyz ->  ...
```

Any illumination would be appreciated.

Comment: You need `^.+$` or `^.*$`, the pattern you have finds 2 matches in the string.

Comment: But why 2 rather than, say, 5 (`Done$`, `one$`, etc.)?

Comment: It must be related to how matching is performed internally to find the substrings to replace. It is a common issue in many regex flavors. Here is a [related issue in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795759/c-mac-os-x-regex-causes-infinite-loop-with-regex-replace/33799633#33799633). The point is that you should not be using a regex matching an empty string in a regex replace method unless you know what you are doing. Or use the anchors as I suggested in the first comment. See [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/TWEK8i).