# C++ regex for overlapping matches

Tags: c++, regex, greedy

I have a string 'CCCC' and I want to match 'CCC' in it, with overlap.

My code:

```
...
std::string input_seq = "CCCC";
std::regex re("CCC");
std::sregex_iterator next(input_seq.begin(), input_seq.end(), re);
std::sregex_iterator end;
while (next != end) {
    std::smatch match = *next;
    std::cout << match.str() << "\t" << "\t" << match.position() << "\t" << "\n";
    next++;
}
...
```

However this only returns

```
CCC 0
```

and skips the `CCC 1` solution, which is needed for me.

I read about non-greedy '?' matching, but I could not make it work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex can be put into the capturing parentheses that can be wrapped with a positive lookahead.

*To make it work on Mac*, too, make sure the regex matches (and thus *consumes*) a single char at each match by placing a `.` (or - to also match line break chars - `[\s\S]`) after the lookahead.

Then, you will need to amend the code to get the first capturing group value like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string input_seq = "CCCC";
    std::regex re("(?=(CCC))."); // <-- PATTERN MODIFICATION
    std::sregex_iterator next(input_seq.begin(), input_seq.end(), re);
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    while (next != end) {
        std::smatch match = *next;
        std::cout << match.str(1) << "\t" << "\t" << match.position() << "\t" << "\n"; // <-- SEE HERE
        next++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/pEziQp)

Output:

```
CCC     0   
CCC     1
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved it. I ll mark this as solved as soon as i can.

Comment: this results in an infinite loop on apple clang.

Comment: @RichardHodges: It must be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795759/c-mac-os-x-regex-causes-infinite-loop-with-regex-replace/33799633#33799633): the Mac realization does not handle empty matches efficiently. A `.` added after the lookahead might solve the problem: [`std::regex re("(?=(CCC)).");`](https://ideone.com/pEziQp). If line break characters must be matched, the `.` should be replaced with `[\s\S]`.

Comment: confirming - this worked on the mac: `"(?=(CCC))."` You may want to edit the answer.