# Grep regex overlap match

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Given the string: `lolololololol`

Grep will not overlap match when I try to find the number of `lol`'s.

```sh
echo "lolololololol" | grep -o 'lol' | wc -l
```

The above snippet returns `3`. When in fact the answer I would like is that there are `6` `lol`'s. For this case I know I could simply grep for `lo`, but this example is meant to represent the general question of how allow grep or some other search tool to find overlapping matches.

#### Other examples

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | grep -E '(^| )[0-9]( |$)'
echo "10101" | grep '101'
```

The best solution can be found at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276159/grep-that-works-with-overlapping-patterns

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in your question. Could you please do add sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then for better understanding of question.

Comment: I don't understand why `[^ ]+` is insufficient. Can you provide the current output versus desired output?

Comment: This part `[^ ]` matches any char except a space, is that intended?

Comment: Looks like the question is oversimplified and the real problem is quite different. Please explain what real-life issue you are having. At least, please provide the expected output for the sample input given.

Comment: After you added the expected output, "*I don't understand why `[^ ]` is insufficient*" x 2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think I get it now. It has to do with subsequences like you showed on https://stackoverflow.com/q/64579766/2191572

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. `$: while IFS="$IFS'" read -ra hits; do (( ${#hits[@]} )) && echo "${hits[@]} (${#hits[@]})"; done < txt`

Comment: If you have found a [good solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276159/grep-that-works-with-overlapping-patterns) either mark this question as a duplicate of that other question, or reproduce that good solution as an answer here.

Comment: you need reputation to mark a question as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you expect to capture the space from the end of one match into the start of the next match:

```
.*?(?=( [^\r\ ]+ ))
```

In `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

string=" 1 -1 1 
 a bc d 
 alpha beta delta "

echo "$string" | grep -Po '.*?(?=( [^\r\n ]+ ))'
```

Using https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online/ it doesn't show the spaces but I believe they are there.

Comment: Notice that `echo $string` (unquoted) replaces all newlines with blanks.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm not much of a bash expert. Can my answer be saved?

Comment: This answer drops the last word off at the end, with `echo "$string"` included

Comment: If you quote, `echo "$string"`, the newlines are preserved, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/3266847).

Comment: @Explorer Gotta be honest, I'm not entire sure of what I'm doing in bash. This is about as close as I can get it.